# How do I keep the Quick Control screen from constantly appearing on my Canon 60D's LCD monitor?

Tags: canon-60d, camera-controls, rear-lcd

The following just happened today:

When I turn on my Canon 60D, the Quick Control screen is shown on the LCD monitor, for the length of the auto power off time. Then power turns off.

Similarly, when I take a picture, the image appears on the LCD for the length of the image review time, and then the Quick Control screen appears. The same when I review images.

This is very annoying. Is there any setting I can use to revert to the standard behavior (when the LCD should be black)?

Comment: Thank You...Thank You...Thank You!!! I was having the same problem as Miguel and a simple Google search revealed this answer, which also solved my problem. I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to respond. Mike

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is one of the modes you enable by pressing the INFO button. If you repeatedly press INFO to cycle through all the display modes you will eventually arrive back to the default mode which turns the LCD off.

Comment: Miguel: Thank you very much! I've spent hours trying to figure out but to no avail. I thought I had destroyed my camera! But it turned out to be false alarm. You saved my life!

Comment: No problem, this puzzled me for a long time as well! In my case this mode enabled itself right after I installed Magic Lantern on my 60D, it seems the ML installer enables it.

Comment: Miguel: You are the best. I too thought I had destroyed my camera! I was just about to go to photo store or cry. I could not find that information anywhere or why it happened. I may have accidentally touched that button or perhaps when I changed lenses?! I love when something so simple for one really can help another!!

Comment: What if I want the info screen to stay on? Everytime I take a picture or review them this screen disappears for me. The screen that shows the mode, shutter speed, aperture, iso, ect… Do I do the same and press the Info button until that screen appears?